# Array manipulating dynamically with an object using javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of object as below.

```
const data =
    [
     {id: 1, recordCreatedTime: '2020-05-08T10:57:35.000Z', name: 'Roy', age: 21, gender: 'Male'},
     {id: 2, name: 'Paul', age: 24,  gender: 'Male'},
     {id: 3, recordCreatedTime: '2020-05-06T11:26:35.000Z', name: 'John', age: 21, gender: 'Male'},
     {id: 4, recordCreatedTime: '2020-05-08T05:11:35.000Z', name: 'Peter', age: 26, gender: 'Female'}
    ]
```

I want to filter the above array with the contents by multiple filter dynamically from the object below. If i add a new element in the `object` below it should work fine. Also if some element miss in the array of object then also the logic should work fine.

```
const object= {recordCreatedTime: "05/08/2020", name: "Peter", gender: "al"}
```

For filtering with `name` it should use `===`, for `gender` it should filter with `includes` and for filtering with `recordCreatedTime` it should filter with `includes` with `MM/DD/YYYY` format. Below is the code i'm using to achieve this, which is not working fine.

```
const result = data.filter(listObject =>
            Object.entries(object).every(
              ([key, value]) =>
                listObject[key] &&
                (listObject[key] === Object.keys(object)[2]
                  ? listObject[key] === value
                  : key === Object.keys(object)[0]
                  ? moment(listObject[key])
                      .format('MM/DD/YYYY')
                      .toString()
                      .includes(value.toString())
                  : listObject[key]
                      .toString()
                      .toLowerCase()
                      .includes(value.toString().toLowerCase()))
            )
          )
```

Can anyone please correct me? The expected output is:

```
[{id: 4, recordCreatedTime: '2020-05-08T05:11:35.000Z', name: 'Peter', age: 26, gender: 'Female'}
        ]
```

Comment: You posted the expected output. What result you getting at the moment? Could you post the actual output?

Comment: It would be much easier to split the filter conditions:
const p1 = obj => condition1
const p2 = obj => condition2
data.filter(x => p1(x) || p(x))

That way you could work on each condition separatly, and write tests for each predicate instead of having to work your way through a combination of predicates.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
    {id: 1, recordCreatedTime: '2020-05-08T10:57:35.000Z', name: 'Roy', age: 21, gender: 'Male'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Paul', age: 24, gender: 'Male'},
    {id: 3, recordCreatedTime: '2020-05-06T11:26:35.000Z', name: 'John', age: 21, gender: 'Male'},
    {id: 4, recordCreatedTime: '2020-05-08T05:11:35.000Z', name: 'Peter', age: 26, gender: 'Female'}
];

const object = {recordCreatedTime: "05/08/2020", name: "Peter", gender: "al"};

const result = data.filter((listObject, i) => {
    let x = false, y = false, z = false;
    Object.entries(object).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if (key === 'recordCreatedTime') {
            x = listObject[key] && ((new Date(listObject[key]).toLocaleDateString()) === new Date(value).toLocaleDateString());
        } else if (key === 'gender') {
            y = listObject[key] && (listObject[key].includes(value));
        } else {
            z = listObject[key] && (listObject[key] === value);
        }
    });

    return x && y && z;
});

console.log(result);
```